# An property of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[1,\infty)$ such that
$$ \sup_{x\in[1,\infty)}\dfrac{|f(x)|}{x+1}<\infty. $$
Does it follow that
$$ \sup_{x\in[1,\infty)}\dfrac{|f(x)|}{x
}<\infty? $$

Edit after 1st comment:

It follows that the answer of above question is true. Now let $g:[1,\infty)\to [1,\infty)$ be a continuous increasing function such that $g(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$ and
$$ \sup_{x\in[1,\infty)}\dfrac{|f(x)|}{g(x+1)}<\infty. $$
Does it follow that
$$ \sup_{x\in[1,\infty)}\dfrac{|f(x)|}{g(x)
}<\infty? $$

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think it should be true but can't proceed. The value of f(x+1) should not be very larger than f(x) as f is continuous. But having a bound on $[1,\infty)$ is the key.

Comment: Let $x \in [1,\infty)$. Then:
$$\frac{|f(x)|}{x} = \frac{|f(x)|}{x+1} \cdot \frac{x+1}{x}$$

What can you deduce from this?

Comment: Okay. Now I get it. Thanks

Comment: You're very welcome

Comment: Your answer led me to ask another problem which I am going to add in the question. Please help me if you can.

Comment: Sure, I will do my best

Comment: You should really try to include your own attempt at the question.

Comment: Think about, in the discrete case, $\frac{n!}{(n - 1)!}$ vs $\frac{n!}{(n-1+1)!}$. If you insist on a continuous version, replace $n!$ with its continuous analogue, $\Gamma(x+1)$, where $\Gamma$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: Here I can't think of any reason to conclude that $g(x+1)/g(x)$ is bounded. So i think in this case, it will be false. But I also can not come up with an example

Comment: Okay thanks. I get it.